# Why are my swiper js slides very big and not showing the right amount I specified

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, swiper.js

I am trying to build a swiper slider with the following layout:

```
<div id="brokerCarousel" class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            @foreach($partners as $partner)
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="{{ $partner->media('logo')->first() !== null ? $partner->media('logo')->first()->getUrl(800,600,'canvas') : '' }}" alt="{{ $partner->name }}">
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then have my JS code:

```
brokerCarousel() {
    if (document.getElementById('brokerCarousel')) {
        new Swiper('#brokerCarousel .swiper-container', {
            slidesPerView: 10,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            autoplay: {
                delay: 2500,
            },
            breakpoints: {
                576: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                },
                768: {
                    slidesPerView: 3,
                },
                1200: {
                    slidesPerView: 5,
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Where I set slides to 5.

My scss:

```
#brokerCarousel {
    &.swiper{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        .swiper-container {
            max-height: 100%;
            .swiper-wrapper {
                .swiper-slide {
                    background-color: #fff;
                    padding: 30px;
                    border-radius: 10px;

                    img {
                        height: 200px;
                        width: auto;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But this is what my slides look like:

[image]

As you can see there are only two slides in view which is wrong by itself but they are also very wide. When I inspect the `.swiper-slide` in my inspector I see this style is applied: `width: 1600px; margin-right: 30px;`. My container is 1440px so one slide can never be 1600px when I have it set to 5.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure the container is 1440px.

Comment: @Raul Yeah the entire swiper is wrapper inside a `.container-fluid` which was `max-width: 1440px;`

Comment: try moving the swiper class on the div with the swiper-container class. That's how I see it in the swiper js docs

Comment: you are calling swiper.js on a class on which you don't also have the "swiper" class which is how it looks on the official docs.

Comment: The problem appears to be the swiper-container div, which I haven't seen used in any  examples or docs. It seemed to work as expected after removing that from the html, css, and js, i.e., initialize #brokerCarousel.